# How to apply math operations to a row of a csv in python?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, math, row

I've been successful creating functions in python and reading/writing files.  However, I really need to apply certain functions to whole **rows** of data (**not columns**) and can't find out anything about how to do this.  The goals are:

- Read a csv or txt file into python (can-do)
- Find a row of data and apply certain conditions and operations
- Do the same with a second row of data
- Then compare results from the rows to each other (done with a similarity function)
- Print the resulting data into a separate file (easy peasy)

Function parameters include "if/then" conditions for ratios, sums, and square roots -- will not include whole function.  For example, just use sum

Here's what I have so far (not much...):

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt ('file_to_read.csv', 
                       dtype=float,
                       delimiter=",",
                       names=True)
np.sum()
print(data)
np.savetxt('test.csv', data, delimiter=',')
```

file_to_read.csv is this:

```
0,2,1
0,2,2
0,2,3
0,1,0
0,2,0
0,3,0
1,0,0
2,0,0
3,0,0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can transpose your matrix or data frame (if using pandas) and work with columns.

Example (pandas):

Original DF

```
In [162]: df
Out[162]:
   a  b  c
0  0  2  1
1  0  2  2
2  0  2  3
3  0  1  0
4  0  2  0
5  0  3  0
6  1  0  0
7  2  0  0
8  3  0  0
```

Transposed DF

```
In [163]: df.T
Out[163]:
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
a  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  2  3
b  2  2  2  1  2  3  0  0  0
c  1  2  3  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Select rows where `b>0` and `c>1`:

```
In [166]: df[(df.b>0) & (df.c>1)]
Out[166]:
   a  b  c
1  0  2  2
2  0  2  3
```

now calculate sum of cells for each found row:

```
In [167]: df[(df.b>0) & (df.c>1)].sum(axis=1)
Out[167]:
1    4
2    5
dtype: int64
```

or product:

```
In [169]: df[(df.b>0) & (df.c>1)].product(axis=1)
Out[169]:
1    0
2    0
dtype: int64
```

PS using `axis=1` instructs Pandas/Numpy to use rows instead of columns